# Why isn't my accessibility tool of enlarging text size working?

Tags: html, css, fonts, size

I'm adding an accessibility tool of users being able to increase the font-size of all the text on the page, and being able to go back to the default font-size if they wanted to. I have made a second CSS file which holds the css rules for the text to increase. However when I click on the icons I made for the text larger/text smaller it does not work. Can anybody understand why? Thanks for the help.

HTML code on the home page:

```
<div id="font-size-buttons">
   <a href="#" onclick="changeCSS('notaccessible.css', 2);"><img src="http://www.me14ch.leedsnewmedia.net/slate/images2/fontmin.png" width="25" height"25" alt="Switch to original text size and colours"></a>
  <a href="#" onclick="changeCSS('stylesheet.css', 2);"><img src="http://www.me14ch.leedsnewmedia.net/slate/images2/fontmax.png" width="30" height="30" alt="Switch to larger text and improved colour contrast"></a>
  </div>
```

Some of the default CSS stylesheet code:

```
.body {
height: 100%;
overflow: auto;
padding-bottom: 25px;
font-size: 0.75em;

}
/* accessibility */

#font-size-buttons {
    float: right;
    clear: both;
    margin-right: 5px;

}
```

And the CSS from the alternative stylesheet:

```
body {
    font-size: 1.5em;

}
```

And the linking stylesheet code at the top of my index.html page:

```
    <link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://me14ch.leedsnewmedia.net/slate/notaccessible.css" rel=alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" title="access"/>
```

The website link: [www.me14ch.leedsnewmedia.net/slate](http://www.me14ch.leedsnewmedia.net/slate)

Answer (score 1):

That's because `changeCSS` is not defined.

in `onclick="....">` you execute a piece of Javascript, in your case a function called `changeCSS` with the variables `'notaccessible.css'` and `2`.

But nowhere in your code you have a function called `changeCSS`. So you either have to write that function, or change your html.

**[edit]**

[made a little example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/82d6yqax/1/)

Comment: Ah yes I see exactly what you mean. I'm new to javascript though, how do I define it?

Comment: You can load an external javascript file by putting `<script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js"></script>` between the `<head>..</head>` tags. In this file you can write all the javascript you want, including a function called `changeCSS` to change the font-size.

Comment: I understand how to link to an external js file, I just don't know how to write the function and am struggling to find any tutorials online that make sense

Comment: Made you a little example, fiddle is in the answer. And you might want to look into cookies as well, to save the user preference. Otherwise everytime someone visits your site, he or she has to change the font size.

Comment: Great i got it to work! Only problem is that the larger text obviously messes up my layout. How can I go about fixing this? I presume its something to do with CSS @Michel

Comment: Grin. One of the problems of flexible layout. Try using `float: left;width:100%;` on your wrapper classes.

Comment: That shifts the whole wrapper to the left when I'd like it centralised with the white space to either side